# Arbitrary non-integer power of a matrix

Tags: analysis, matrices

does there exist the notion of a non-integer power of a matrix? This seems to be accessible via semigroup-theory, yet I have not seen an actual definition so far.

I am not too firm at this right now, but I am curious. Can you give me a sketch of the definition and provide with some introductory information?

Comment: There is useful discussion in answers to [this duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364613/can-you-raise-a-matrix-to-a-non-integer-number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several techniques for extending scalar functions to matrices.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) mentions techniques based on power series, eigendecomposition, Jordan decomposition, Cauchy integral, and more.

Comment: (I'm surprised this is the accepted answer.  I'm used to link-only answers being discouraged.  In this case it's not immediate where one should look on the linked page.)

Comment: @Mars, this is an answer from the very early days. I've tried to improve it. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 6):

If your matrix has positive eigenvalues, then one definition is to take non-integer powers of each eigenvalue (but keep the eigenvectors the same).  This is a common definition used to take square roots, for example.

Comment: The more general condition is that the eigenvalues should not be negative numbers; see e.g. [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=S6gpNn1JmbgC&pg=PA173).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to define powers for appropriate matrices.

Comment: Does the square root of a matrix defined with this approach coincide with the canoical square root $\sqrt(A^\ast A )$?