# Can you raise a Matrix to a non integer number?

Tags: matrices, irrational-numbers, exponentiation

So I heard you can take a matrix A to the power 2, take it to a -3th power and multiply it by an irrational number. You can also do some other non-intuitive things like taking e to the power of a matrix.

Does there exist some definition to take a nxn matrix to a power like 2.3 or pi?

Comment: [See this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16739/arbitrary-non-integer-power-of-a-matrix).  and [this](http://www.blackmesapress.com/Eigenvalues.htm)

Comment: [Functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort of.

First, we have to ask what $f(x) = a^x$ means for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.  Assuming that $a > 0$, we can write:
$$
f(x) = a^x = \left( e^{\ln(a)}\right) ^x = e^{(\ln a)x},
$$
so it boils down to having a sensible definition of the *natural* exponential and logarithm functions.

The exponential function [can be defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) by its Maclaurin series:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \tfrac{1}{2}x^2 + \tfrac{1}{6}x^3 + \cdots
$$

One has to, of course, verify that this infinite series *converges* for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for this definition to make sense.

The same series can be used to define the [matrix exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), interpreting $x$ now as an $n \times n$ matrix.  (It also converges for all matrices.)

*But, here the analogy begins to fall apart.*

First of all, the [matrix logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) is a much more finicky creature.  The standard Mercator series for the logarithm doesn't converge for all matrices.  Even if we extend our ground field to the complex numbers, then a matrix has a logarithm [if and only if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence) it's invertible.  Even when *a* logarithm exists, it is not unique!

Comment: Of course, the non-uniqueness of logarithms already happens for (complex) numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I've never thought about this question, but what about the following. Recall that $a^b=e^{b \ln(a)}$. Define the log of a matrix A as a matrix B such that $e^B=A$. This exists, allowing complex numbers, iff A is invertible.

Also recall that we can define $e^A = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k$. So what about defining $A^{2.3} = e^{2.3 \ln{A}} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (2.3 \ln(A))^k$ which converges iff $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

To me (with the benefit of much hindsight), the most natural way to define $A^\beta$ where $\beta$ is a non-integer real number is to define
$$
A^\beta = e^{\beta\log A}.
$$
Here $\log A$ is the [logarithm of the matrix $A$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_logarithm#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix) (which exists whenever $A$ is invertible), and $e^C$ is the [exponential of the matrix $C$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) (which always exists).

Comment: great minds think alike?

Comment: everyone's invited to the party!

Answer (score 2):

When the power is a rational number, like $1/2$, you might be referring to a whole family of matrices. For instance $I^{1/2}$ could be interpreted as all of the matrices $A$ such that $A^2=I$. there are lots of these: any reflection will do.

In general $B^{m/n}$ could mean the collection of all matrices $A$ such that $A^n=B^m$.

This usage is not uncommon, so if you adopt @Josh, @Greg, and @Sammy's (Hi Sammy!) definitive meaning for $B^q$, then it's good to be aware of the other usage.